# rest API working in postman but not in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, postman, resttemplate

Im trying to implement this API https://api.bnm.gov.my/portal#operation/ERLatest

As per the above URL, its GET request with mandatory Accept herader with value "application/vnd.BNM.API.v1+json"

when i tried with postman, can get response ->

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "currency_code": "AUD",
            "unit": 1,
            "rate": {
                "date": "2020-05-04",
                "buying_rate": 2.7454,
                "selling_rate": 2.7904,
                "middle_rate": null
            }
        },
        {
            "currency_code": "CAD",
            "unit": 1,
            "rate": {
                "date": "2020-05-04",
                "buying_rate": 3.0465,
                "selling_rate": 3.0915,
                "middle_rate": null
            }
        },
        {
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "unit": 1,
            "rate": {
                "date": "2020-05-04",
                "buying_rate": 4.7336,
                "selling_rate": 4.7786,
                "middle_rate": null
            }
        },
        {
            "currency_code": "GBP",
            "unit": 1,
            "rate": {
                "date": "2020-05-04",
                "buying_rate": 5.3769,
                "selling_rate": 5.4269,
                "middle_rate": null
            }
        },
        {
            "currency_code": "JPY",
            "unit": 100,
            "rate": {
                "date": "2020-05-04",
                "buying_rate": 4.0464,
                "selling_rate": 4.0914,
                "middle_rate": null
            }
        },
        {
            "currency_code": "SGD",
            "unit": 1,
            "rate": {
                "date": "2020-05-04",
                "buying_rate": 3.0368,
                "selling_rate": 3.0788,
                "middle_rate": null
            }
        },
        {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "unit": 1,
            "rate": {
                "date": "2020-05-04",
                "buying_rate": 4.33,
                "selling_rate": 4.355,
                "middle_rate": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "quote": "rm",
        "session": "1130",
        "last_updated": "2020-05-04 12:16:13",
        "total_result": 7
    }
}
```

This is what i did to get the same response in my spring boot application ->

```
@RequestMapping(value="/forex_check")
public String forexExchange() throws Exception{
    String url="https://api.bnm.gov.my/public/exchange-rate/USD";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", "application/vnd.BNM.API.v1+json");
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,entity,String.class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

But it fails to get the correct response, what im getting is ->

```
The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.

Your support ID is: 10497884431577109860
```

When i was playing around postman, i have noticed that, when i remove the HOST header i do get this same type of response. But as far as i know, HOST header are automatically set. Is it spring boot RestTemplate will not set this HOST header? if not how to set it manually?

Thank you guys....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution is to manually set User-Agent header

in your forexExchange() controller method just add this line where you set your headers:
`headers.set("User-Agent", "test");` so it looks like this:

```
    public String forexExchange() throws Exception{
        String url="https://api.bnm.gov.my/public/exchange-rate/USD";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Accept", "application/vnd.BNM.API.v1+json");
        headers.set("User-Agent", "test");
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,entity,String.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why "User-Agent" header is required?

Comment: It is used as anti-spam protection on their back-end side, and RestTemplate does not provide a default one so we need to provide it manually

Comment: It works! thank you for the explanation too. Marked as correct answer.